# How do find the value of implementation specific defines?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am using a variation of GCC that is specific to ARM microprocessors, and I am trying to figure out what this macro is doing in stdint.h.

```
   #if defined(__GNUC__) && \
    ( (__GNUC__ >= 4) || \
    ( (__GNUC__ >= 3) && defined(__GNUC_MINOR__) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 2) ) )
    /* gcc > 3.2 implicitly defines the values we are interested */ 
    #define __STDINT_EXP(x) __##x##__
    #else
    #define __STDINT_EXP(x) x
    #include <limits.h>
    #endif
```

`__GNUC__` is an implementation specific macro, but how would you find out what the compiler is using for this?  `Printf()` wouldn't work for this compiler because it's output is for an embedded system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc's option `-dM` spits you all macros that are defined internally. Something like

```
gcc -xc -dM -E /dev/null | sort | less
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `#pragma message "__GNUC__=" __GNUC__` to output it at compile time.
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: I actually don't get any value for `__GNUC__` when doing this.  The limits.h file would be included if it wasn't, which makes senses. But it seems like `__GNUC__` is version information that would always get defined...

Answer (score 3):

To expand it alone, just

```
    echo __GNUC__ | cc -E -
```

To expand the file containing it, `cc -E`*filename*